# Are votes poorly named?

Tags: discussion

Whenever you look at a question, it displays the number of "votes". However, this isn't true. For example, a question might have a number of "votes" of -2, but this could be achieved in numerous ways. There could have been three votes, one up and two down, or 56 down and 54 up. Not to mention that having a negative quantity of votes is absurd.

[image: Votes is misleading]

Granted, this conundrum relies on the user interpreting the plural of votes as a quantity, but I feel like it would be more accurate to use replace "votes" with "score" or something of the like.

Comment: If something is at -1(+10,-11) and -1(+100, -101) doesn't that mean the same thing?  More then half the people thought it was bad.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the concept of having a -1 substitution for say +100,-101, and I think it is an entirely useful statistic. However, to say that there is a negative quantity of votes is absurd.

Comment: Absurd in what sense? Grammatically?

Comment: Logically. Although votes may carry a negative value, there can not be a negative quantity of votes. And absurd because the number representing the quantity of votes is distinct from the difference between positive and negative-valued votes.

Comment: So would you have it rather be called score?  That is what they call it for purposes of tag badges(and maybe some other things).

Comment: Not necessarily score, but something other than votes, yes.

Comment: MSE duplicate: [Use “score” instead of “votes” in the list of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153515/167646)

Comment: you can see this [numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) if you have the Reputation for it

Comment: It is a sensible choice, it re-enforces the notion to users that they can alter the number by voting.  Not by, erm, kicking a soccer ball or being popular with the girls :)